# What can be a limit to the maximum possible power of a pilot signal

Tags: digital-communications, signal-detection, channel-estimation

In practice, what can be a limit to the maximum power of a pilot signal in wireless communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit other than what is imposed by the FCC and underlying hardware. Any commercial/consumer device has an operating power defined either on the device or in the manual. The max power of the signal (and pilot) will be within those bounds.